Need help for translating old signs
Dear all, I recently bought this painting and I would be keen to understand the meaning of the painted signs. Can anyone please help? Thanks a lot.

the text in seal script is “
公公上荊衛大
墓阿柱州大唐
誌史國大將故
之那薛都軍右
銘貞國督贈驍
“
read it as “大唐故右驍衛大將軍贈荊州大都督上柱國薛國公阿史那貞公墓誌之銘”
the owner surname is 阿史那 “asena”, given name “忠”, posthumous name “貞”
https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hant/%E9%98%BF%E5%8F%B2%E9%82%A3%E5%BF%A0
have fun :)

Thanks a lot for your useful answer! Kind regards
